# error permision ACCESS_FIND_LOCATION

Tags: android

I'm using permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` but when run.error:requires `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission`
why?

thanks in advance.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: can you share your code and error??

Comment: [check this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`  and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` both permission required when to trying to get location 
 so add this both permission in manifest file as well as if you targeting android 6.0 and above than add this runtime permsiion  like below code

```
   String permission = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.
                    checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchCityClass.this, new String[]
                        {permission}, PERMISSION_GPS_CODE);

            }
```

**now handle permisiion result**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_GPS_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            Toast.makeText(this, "location_permission_granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "location_permission_not_granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you write run time permissions in your code? As from Android 6.0, for every permission stated in manifest, must also be asked run time from user.

```
private void requestLocationPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
}
```

Also handle user's response as well:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE: {
            //If permission is granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```